# Запуск анимации в зоне видимости

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема что при скролле анимация перезапускается.
https://codepen.io/lomakin/pen/eYBJYYR

Функция определения видимости

```
var block_show = null;
function scrollTracking(element){
    var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var et = $(element).offset().top;
    var eh = $(element).outerHeight();

    if (wt + wh >= et && wt + wh - eh * 2 <= et + (wh - eh)){
        if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
            block_show = true;
        }

    } else {
        if (block_show == null || block_show == true) {
            block_show = false;
        }

    }
    return block_show;
}
```

Отслеживание

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(scrollTracking('#Vector') === true){
        linePatint1('#Vector');
    }
    if(scrollTracking('.wecan__header') === true){
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__1', 1600);
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__2', 2000);
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__3', 2600);
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(scrollTracking('#Vector') === true){
        linePatint1('#Vector');
    }
    if(scrollTracking('.wecan__header') === true){
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__1', 1600);
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__2', 2000);
        linePatint2('.wecan-line__3', 2600);
    }
});
```

Функци linePatint1,linePatint2 запускают нужную анимацию

Comment: а просто intersectionObserver применить - проще и кода в 100 раз меньше

Comment: @Sevastopol' прикрепил

Comment: @MaximLensky не знаю такого ) Почитаем. Есть может пример ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: вот здесь подробно описан механизм: https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=494670

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                const block = entry.target;
                linePatint2('.contact-line__1', 500);
                observer.unobserve(block);
            }
        })
    }, {
        threshold: .5
    })
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('.contact__header'));
```